# When Building my exe it cant find my database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I build my project on the computer with Visual basic my exe file works but as soon as I open the exe on my server I get an error that I think it doesn't my database. Doesn't this get compiled at the same time as my whole program? I see the database in the folder it gets compiled to. And any pictures I have load are the right connection string to the server. Not sure if I am missing anything else. This is the error it gives:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52
>   - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database
>   Runtime feature is enabled.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable)    at
>   Shipping_Bible.Client_CodeDataSet1TableAdapters.ClientTableAdapter.Fill(ClientDataTable
>   dataTable) in C:\Users\CMike\Desktop\Shipping Bible\Shipping
>   Bible\Client_CodeDataSet1.Designer.vb:line 1908    at
>   Shipping_Bible.FrmBible.FrmBible_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\CMike\Desktop\Shipping Bible\Shipping Bible\FrmBible.vb:line
>   23    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:2,State:0,Class:20
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Shipping Bible
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Shared/Common/Data/Shipping%20Bible/Shipping%20Bible.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualBasic
>       Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 14.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Core
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Runtime.Remoting
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Numerics
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Thank you

Comment: Post your connectionstring. The most relevant part of the error is probably: *provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)*

Comment: Not sure where t go to get my connection string as I did it through server explorer, then from there connected to my database. I don't see it coded anywhere? How can I see if SQL Server Express is properly installed and if the runtime feature is enabled?

Comment: Connection string will probably be in appsettings.json, app.config or settings.settings (in solution explorer). It's probably a reasonable bet that your server doesn't have sqlexpress installed and config'd for localdb use. What db software is installed on the server?

Comment: we have PostgreSQL 9.3. Not sure if that helps. In the app.config:
        <add name="Shipping_Bible.My.MySettings.Client_CodeConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\Client Code.mdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="Shipping_Bible.My.MySettings.Client_CodeConnectionString1"
            connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\Client Code.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Well that's an error message fro an app that's created with SqlServer in mind, which is Microsoft's flagship DB, which is a very different thing to Postgres and absolutely not compatible; You'll either need to switch to using NPgSQL driver/provider and code for postgres, or install SQLServer on the server

Comment: That is what's under the app.config in-between the <connectionstrings> and </connectionstrings>

Comment: And that confirms that there are actually a couple fo MS technologies in use there - Access being a sort of low end single user database and SQLServer being the only one you'd *want* to use in a choice between the two ;) - you now have a decision to make; install SQLServer, or re-code for Postgres. Throw Access away in either case. Hopefully it's still there purely as a hangover from an earlier iteration

Comment: I did a short install of visual studious for the server part and it works thank you. I wouldn't know how to change to code for postgres

Comment: *"I wouldn't know how to change to code for postgres"*. If only the internet existed and you could search for information on how to connect to PostgreSQL from a VB.NET app.

Comment: I thought the whole programming would have to change not just how to connect the two.